# Filtering only on Annotations in Django

Tags: django, orm

Taking the example from:
http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#filter-and-exclude

```
Publisher.objects.filter(book__rating__gt=3.0).annotate(num_books=Count('book'))
```

Is there anyway to have the filter only apply to the annotation, so it would return all publishers, with some having a num_books=0?

Comment: So, you want a list of all publishers, each annotated with their number of highly-rated books?

Comment: Yes, and that list should include publishers that have no books or only books with low ratings.

Answer (score 35):

You can use the annotation variable in the filter.

```
publishers=Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book')).filter(num_books__gte=2)
```

Comment: I mean, I want all publishers to be returned, and each publisher should be annotated with the number of books with high ratings. So, included in the publisher list should be publishers with less than 2 books with high ratings, and publishers with only low rated books, and publishers who have no books at all. Let me know if I can clarify that better.

Answer (score 11):

Hm, I think you have to use an [extra clause](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

```
Publisher.objects.extra(select={
    'num_books': 'SELECT COUNT(*) ' + \
                 'FROM <your_app>_book ' + \
                 'WHERE <your_app>_book.publisher_id = ' + \
                       '<your_app>_publisher.id AND ' + \
                       'rating > 3.0'
})
```

Comment: This is the best answer I've seen so far. It would be nice if I didn't have to use raw sql though.

Comment: That's true! This shouldn't cause any compatibility problems, though. But please let me know, if you discover a way to do this without raw sql!

Comment: You can probably use QuerySet._as_sql(connection) method, to generate raw query by Django itself. Little hack but still better than write it itself.

Comment: this seems exactly as if I added a property to my model to do this filter, and would cause n+1 issues, right?

Comment: @NathanTregillus It would not create any additional queries, as it is all done in SQL. It would be a little slower just because the query is more complex, but nothing like one query for every object.

Comment: This used to be a good answer, but is outdated in 2017.  The [django docs for extra](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#extra) say this method is deprecated, and to only use it as a last resort.  They go as far as asking you to open a ticket for your use case so they can support it with `annotate`.

Answer (score 11):

```
from django.db import models

Publisher.objects.annotate(
    num_books=models.Sum(
        models.Case(
            models.When(
                book__rating__gt=3.0,
                then=1,
            ),
            default=0,
            output_field=models.IntegerField(),
        )
    )
).filter(
    num_books=0,
)
```

Comment: That looks close, except don't filter by "num_books=0" at the end. All publishers should be returned.

Answer (score 9):

Starting Django 2.0 one may use [`filter`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/querysets/#aggregate-filter) parameter of aggregation function:

```
from django.db.models import Q    
Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book', filter=Q(book__rating__gt=3.0)))
```

The answer is based on a [cheat sheet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/aggregation/#cheat-sheet).

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like:

```
Book.objects.values('publisher').annotate(num_books=Count('id'))
```

Comment: That would be a count of all books, not just the ones that have a rating greater than 3.

Answer (score 0):

I just facing this kind of problem. And if my interpreation for the problem and expected solution is correct, this is my working solution:

`Publisher.objects.annotate(num_books=Count('book')).filter(book__rating__gt=3.0)`

Just swap filter & annotate position. This is done in Django version 1.9

Comment: That's the exact same code I have in my question (not even swapped). The problem I was having is that it doesn't show publishers that have 0 books. I don't want to filter the publishers at all, I just want to filter the count.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to edit your sample code. But this is what I was implementing when I want to use filter & annotate in my queryset. And unfortunately, I haven't read your question clearly about 0 book publisher.