# Django queryset order filter

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have two model objects and they have a many to many relationship -

```
class Note(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    body = models.TextField()
    is_deleted = models.BooleanField()

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{} - {}".format(self.title, self.body)

class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
    notes = models.ManyToManyField(Note)
```

I'm trying to order Tag object based on the count of non-deleted Notes. I can use `Tag.objects.annotate(notes_count=Count('notes')).order_by('-notes_count')` to order by count of notes, but this count includes notes that have deleted flag as true. My question is, how can I run this to order Tags by count of non-deleted notes (i.e. note.is_deleted=False)?

I tried defining a method in Tag that returns non-deleted notes only, i.e. -

```
def non_deleted_notes(self):
    return self.notes.filter(is_deleted=False)
```

And then replacing `Count('notes')` with `Count('non_deleted_notes')`, but that results in an error.

Comment: What error does it result in?

Comment: `FieldError at /`
`Cannot resolve keyword 'non_deleted_notes' into field. Choices are: id, notes, tag_name`

Comment: aggregation queries work at the database level. they can't be based on model methods

Answer (score 1):

i don't think this is supported by the queryset api, so you may need to resort to [`.extra()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096580/filtering-only-on-annotations-in-django)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. This is what I'm using now, unless a better suggestion comes along - `Tag.objects.annotate(notes_count=Count('id')).order_by('-notes_count').extra(tables=['scriblets_tag', 'scriblets_tag_notes', 'scriblets_note'], where=['scriblets_tag.id = scriblets_tag_notes.tag_id', 'scriblets_tag_notes.note_id = scriblets_note.id', 'scriblets_note.is_deleted=%s'], params=[False])`

Comment: For the curious, this is the query that is generated by Django - `SELECT "scriblets_tag"."id", "scriblets_tag"."tag_name", COUNT("scriblets_tag"."id") AS "notes_count" FROM "scriblets_tag" , "scriblets_tag_notes" , "scriblets_note" WHERE scriblets_tag.id = scriblets_tag_notes.tag_id AND scriblets_tag_notes.note_id = scriblets_note.id AND scriblets_note.is_deleted=False GROUP BY "scriblets_tag"."id", "scriblets_tag"."tag_name" ORDER BY "notes_count" DESC`