# apply filter only on one annotate columns without effect on other annotate columns?

Tags: python, django, annotations

i grouped by a value then sum of a field , but now i want to only summation happen if a column inside `annotate` greater that or equal to 1 !

my models.py

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    order = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()

class Prodcut(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenth=20)
    cost = models.IntegerField()
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

this is my query

```
MyModel.objects.values('name__name').annotate(
            income=(
                    Sum(((F('price')*F('order')) - (
                        (F('name__price')+F('name__cost'))*F('order'))
                            ),output_field=IntegerField())),quantity=(
                                        Sum(F('order'))
                                    ))
```

sometimes happen income smaller than 0 (negative values) , i dont want summation of those products which their incomes smaller than 0 , i want to use something like this inside the `annotate` or `Sum` `income__gte=1` !? ,

i have some more
fields i dont want to use `.filter` at the end of `)annotate`

is it possible only add to income column if the new income greater than or equal to 1?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Filtering only on Annotations in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096580/filtering-only-on-annotations-in-django)

Comment: Surely when a product's price + cost is greater than the charged price a negative income is valid?

Comment: @ReinstateMonica i want to filter by the income columns not others , it doesnt work in my case

Comment: @IainShelvington yes negative result happens sometimes (when i sell something which have no any income , its loss

Comment: @IainShelvington i dont want to count negative results to my income , without using .filter at the end , because it affect on my other annotate columns

Comment: Can you share your model(s)?

Comment: @IainShelvington updated , i much appreciate your helps

Comment: @IainShelvington isnt there something we can do ?

Comment: Just to clarify. You want a queryset of all `MyModel` with each result annotated with `income` and income is either greater than 0 or 0?

Comment: imagine , i make a post on MyModel(name=mouse ,order=2,price=20) and in my Product model i have these information for mouse product Product(name=mouse,cost=4,price=10) , when i calculate to find income for this product : (2 *20) - ((4+10)*2) => 40 - 28 = 12 , but sometimes happen the result will be a negative price  when (2*10) - ((4+10)*2) => 20 - 28 = -8

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a second annotation that filters the first annotation. In this case you can use [`Greatest`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#greatest) to return 0 if the actual income is negative

```
from django.db.models.functions import Greatest
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    actual_income=F('price') * F('order') - (F('name__price') + F('name__cost')) * F('order'),
).annotate(
    income=Greatest(F('actual_income'), 0)
)
```

I often find it make things clearer to use multiple named annotations

```
MyModel.objects.annotate(
    total_charged=F('price') * F('order'),
    total_paid=(F('name__price') + F('name__cost')) * F('order')
).annotate(
    revenue=F('total_charged') - F('total_paid')
).annotate(
    income=Greatest(F('revenue'), 0)
)
```

Comment: its worked as magic , i appreciate you , saved my night

Comment: is there something similar to Smallest ? i also want to calculate negative number ?

Comment: There is `Least` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/database-functions/#least

Comment: sorry i got a problem , it only prevent income reaching negative values and stop in 0 if a negative value appeared , and still calculate with negative values ?

Comment: MyModel is only related to 1 product? What do you mean it stops? Do you have another annotation/filter after this?

Comment: no i have multi products with different price and costs,whenever income column reach negatives it only display 0 in background for example its -5 showing 0 till a new income with  greater than 5 then (if new income =6) income will be 1,  yes i have multiple annotation , i've updated with the other annotation (quantity)

Comment: it should be something before Sum function happened

Comment: should i give up on it to solve? or we can do something else please ?

Comment: can we use if else in Sum? i tried but it seems if else not work if not it will solve the issue

Comment: i made a new post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62606945/django-using-if-else-or-while-else-inside-sum-function-with-annotation-cannot if could help please let me know